# How to deploy Vue CLI project to DigitalOcean App Platform from Container Registry?

Tags: docker, nginx

My reference is here >> [docker-nginx](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#docker-nginx) to build my docker image and already pushed to DigitalOcean Container Registry. But per trying to deploy this container on DO Apps, always encounter this error message:

```
starting container: starting non-root container [/docker-entrypoint.sh nginx -g daemon off;]: creating process: failed to load /docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error
```